# filter ping result with grep and awk altogether doesn't work

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

I want to pipe the ping output with only its delay time to a text.
while I do , I get this as expected

```
ping somesite 
PING somesite  (220.181.57.217) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 220.181.57.217: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=43.4 ms
64 bytes from 220.181.57.217: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=43.7 ms
64 bytes from 220.181.57.217: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=43.4 ms
```

Then I do this

```
ping somesite | awk -F '[:=]'  '{print $5}'

43.3 ms
43.2 ms
43.3 ms
43.2 ms
43.2 ms
43.1 ms
43.1 ms
43.3 ms
43.2 ms
43.6 ms
43.3 ms
43.3 ms
```

So The first line is blank, then I figured I had to get rid of it first.

```
ping somesite | grep -v "PING" | awk -F '[:=]'  '{print $5}'
```

But there isn't any output.
When I do either

```
ping somesite | grep -v "PING"
```

or

```
 ping somesite | awk -F '[:=]'  '{print $5}'
```

It will work. When putting them together. It won't.
I'd like to know the reason for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not getting any output when piping with `grep` **due to block buffering** in `grep` command.

You can make `grep` use the **line buffering** so get the output for each line:

```
ping google.com | grep --line-buffered -v "PING" | awk -F '[:=]' '{print $5}'
```

However **you don't need `grep`** because you can do this using single `awk`:

```
ping google.com | awk -F '[:=]' 'NR>1{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With a small modification:

```
ping somesite | awk -F '[:=]'  'NR!=1 {print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out by the answer from 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/562344/what-does-grep-line-buffering-do

So pretty much grep buffers the output until 4096 bytes before sending the lines to awk. The grep option --line-buffered will solve my problem.

Comment: Please avoid posting this as a separate answer as I've already covered it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checking with NR (Number of records)actually remove first record from the output,

```
ping somesite | awk -F '[:=]'  'NR!=1 {print $5}'
```

or

```
ping somesite | awk -F '[:=]'  'NR>1 {print $5}'
```

You can check with NF (Number of fields) to filter any such record which doesn't fit in pattern,

```
ping somesite | awk -F '[:=]'  'NF==5 {print $5}'
```