# How to filter CMD command results?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am making a simple ping tool batch script. 
And I would like to filter the output the CMD gives, using the ping command.
Normally the output of a ping would be like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=52
```

But I would like to filter out the size of the packets the ttl, and change the Reply text. So that it would look more like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply: time=21ms
```

I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162250/filter-ping-result-with-grep-and-awk-altogether-doesnt-work) post that I should be able to do that with a `awk -F` argument, however trying that in my script just closes the CMD window on opening. 
How could I do what I want to do?

My script right now:

```
@ECHO OFF


:PING
cls & set /p address=Host to ping: 
@echo Started pinging at: %time%

ping %address%  /t  & echo. & pause. & goto :PING
```

Comment: use [`FOR /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your provided information, here's a quick example using `FOR /F`, *as indicated in the [comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885287/how-to-filter-cmd-command-results#comment107720671_60885287)*.

```batch-file
@Echo Off

:PingIt
ClS
Set /P "IP=Host to ping: "
Echo "%IP%"|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "\"[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\"">NUL^
 ||GoTo PingIt
Echo Started pinging at: %TIME%
For /F "Tokens=1-7,9" %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%PING.EXE" %IP%|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "ms$ data""'
)Do If "%%N"=="" (Echo(%%G %%H %%I %%J %%K %%L %%M)Else Echo Reply: time=%%N
Pause
```

The code includes a 'better than nothing' validation of your end user's input, before trying to use it as an IP Address. It also includes an optional `Pause` command, included only to show you the output before the cmd.exe window closes, *(dependent upon your method of invoking the script)*.

Please note that the example does not cater for responses which fail the ping, e.g. `Request timed out.`. These cases are outside of the scope of your question so I have left it to you to deal with yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help.